# Constructor overwrites previous values of already created object

Tags: python, oop

I'm relatively new to Python. I was working in a project to create objects Square and Points. A Square is composed of 4 points which are the upper left corner, upper right corner and so on.

Now in my main function I create 4 point objects and I send them to the constructor of Square class, it creates my Square.

When I do the same for another Square with different values for the point objects, the values for my previously created Square are overwritten, so at the end I have two same objects. Do you know why this is happening?

This is my code:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Square(object):
    ul = Point()
    ll = Point()
    ur = Point()
    lr = Point()
    def __init__(self, ul, ll, ur, lr):
        self.ul.x = ul.x
        self.ll.x = ll.x
        self.ur.x = ur.x
        self.lr.x = lr.x
        self.ul.y = ul.y
        self.ll.y = ll.y
        self.ur.y = ur.y
        self.lr.y = lr.y

def main():
    ul1 = Point(1, 2)
    ll1 = Point(1, 1)
    ur1 = Point(2, 2)
    lr1 = Point(2, 1)
    s1 = Square(ul1, ll1, ur1, lr1)

    ul2 = Point(3, 3)
    ll2 = Point(3, 2)
    ur2 = Point(4, 3)
    lr2 = Point(4, 2)
    s2 = Square(ul2, ll2, ur2, lr2)

    #At this point s1 and s2 have the same values...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated ;)

Cheers!

Comment: you only really need two points to describe a square: opposing corners (i.e. corners across the diagonal from one another)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's happening because you've defined the four corner variables in the `Square` class as class variables. This means that they are shared between all instances of that class.

Here's a cleaner version of your `Square` class. There are instance variables `self.ul, self.ll` and so forth. You don't need to specify a `Point` instance for these in the `__init__` because you're already doing that in the main function where you pass them as arguments.

```
class Square(object):
    def __init__(self, ul, ll, ur, lr):
        self.ul = ul
        self.ll = ll
        self.ur = ur
        self.lr = lr 

def main():
    s1 = Square(Point(1, 2), Point(1, 1), Point(2, 2), Point(2, 1))
    s2 = Square(Point(3, 3), Point(3, 2), Point(4, 3), Point(4, 2))
    print s1.ul.x # 1
    print s1.lr.y # 2
```

HyperBoreus makes a good point about passing points as arguments, as if you pass the same point object to two squares and modify it, any changes you make will reflect in both squares.

You can get around this by passing corner values to the `__init__` instead of `Point` objects, and then create the instances in the `__init`__

Here's a complete example:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Square(object):
    def __init__(self, ul, ll, ur, lr):
        self.ul = Point(ul[0], ul[1])
        self.ll = Point(ll[0], ll[1])
        self.ur = Point(ur[0], ur[1])
        self.lr = Point(lr[0], lr[1])

def main():
    square_one = Square((1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 1))
    square_two = Square((3, 3), (3, 2), (4, 3), (4, 2))
```

I'd also advice you to use more readable variable names. You save nothing by shortening `upper_right` to `ur`. On the contrary, when you return to this code in a year, you'll curse at yourself.

Comment: `self.ul` is undefined and hence `self.ul.x = ul.x` will fail. I guess you meant something like `self.ul = Point (ul.x, ul.y)`.

Comment: Now the thing is that you don't create new instances of the points. I.e. if you pass one point to two squares and mutate this point once, both squares will be affected. I don't know if this matters for OP. Maybe you could point out both approaches: `self.ul = ul` vs `self.ul = Point (ul.x, ul.y)`... The curse of mutability.

Comment: I appreciate your answers!